# AWS Lambda and Cognito error on deploy: Only one request to update this UserPool can be processed at a time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

In my AWS project, I use the serverless framework to deploy lambda functions and a Cognito user pool.

I want 2 of my lambda functions to be triggered by Cognito user pool events, so here is what I did:

```
functions:

  autoMoveToUserGroup:
    handler: src/auto-move-to-user-group.handler
    name: auto-move-to-user-group
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: test-user-pool
          trigger: PostAuthentication
          existing: True

  autoValidationUserEmailModification:
    handler: src/auto-validation-user-email-modification.handler
    name: auto-validation-user-email-modification
    events:
      - cognitoUserPool:
          pool: test-user-pool
          trigger: CustomMessage
          existing: True

resources:

  Resources:

    MyCognitoUserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        UserPoolName: test-user-pool
        AutoVerifiedAttributes:
          - email
        UsernameAttributes:
          - email
        Schema:
          - Name: email
            Required: True
```

When I deploy using the `serverless deploy` command, I sometimes got the following error:

```
An error occurred: AutoDashvalidationDashuserDashemailDashmodificationCustomCognitoUserPool1 - Failed to create resource.
Only one request to update this UserPool can be processed at a time.
```

It looks like a random bug, since it doesn’t occurs everytime (happens very often, though). Also, when it occurs, it doesn’t always occurs on the same function.

Did I do something wrong? How can I fix that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so here is a workaround: without using the `events` part in the serverless syntax, we can do this only using raw CloudFormation syntax:

```
resources:

  Resources:

    MyCognitoUserPool:
      Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
      Properties:
        ...
        LambdaConfig:
          CustomMessage: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:123456789012:function:auto-validation-user-email-modification

    lambdaCognitoPermissionCustomMessage:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      Properties: 
        Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
        FunctionName: !Ref 'AutoValidationUserEmailModificationLambdaFunction'
        Principal: cognito-idp.amazonaws.com
        SourceArn: !GetAtt
          - MyCognitoUserPool
          - Arn
```

Also, according to the serverless team, it's actually a bug that should be fixed and deployed on August, 14th 2019.

Hope it helps.